# Using Backbone-relational with CoffeeScript

Tags: debugging, scope, coffeescript, backbone-relational

I'm trying to use a Backbone-relational and CoffeeScript in a project.The following is an example in CoffeeScript of the type of things I'm trying to model :

```
  class NestedModel extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    defaults:
     Description: 'A nested model'

  NestedModel.setup()

  class MainModel extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    defaults:
     Description: 'A MainModel description'
     StartDate: null

    relations: [
      type: Backbone.HasOne
      key:  'nestedmodel'
      relatedModel: 'NestedModel'
      includeInJSON: '_id'
      reverseRelation:
        type: Backbone.HasOne
        includeInJSON: '_id'
        key: 'mainmodel'   
    ]

  MainModel.setup()     

  nm = new NestedModel()
  mm = new MainModel(nestedmodel: nm)
  console.log mm.get("nestedmodel").get("mainmodel").get("Description")
  return
```

That CoffeeScript produces the following JavaScript:

```
  var MainModel, NestedModel, mm, nm;
  var __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, __extends = function(child, parent) {
    for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; }
    function ctor() { this.constructor = child; }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor;
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
  };
  NestedModel = (function() {
    __extends(NestedModel, Backbone.RelationalModel);
    function NestedModel() {
      NestedModel.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    NestedModel.prototype.defaults = {
      Description: 'A nested model'
    };
    return NestedModel;
  })();
  NestedModel.setup();
  MainModel = (function() {
    __extends(MainModel, Backbone.RelationalModel);
    function MainModel() {
      MainModel.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    MainModel.prototype.defaults = {
      Description: 'A MainModel description',
      StartDate: null
    };
    MainModel.prototype.relations = [
      {
        type: Backbone.HasOne,
        key: 'nestedmodel',
        relatedModel: 'NestedModel',
        includeInJSON: '_id',
        reverseRelation: {
          type: Backbone.HasOne,
          includeInJSON: '_id',
          key: 'mainmodel'
        }
      }
    ];
    return MainModel;
  })();
  MainModel.setup();
  nm = new NestedModel();
  mm = new MainModel({
    nestedmodel: nm
  });
  console.log(mm.get("nestedmodel").get("mainmodel").get("Description"));
  return;
```

Which produces the following warning and error

```
Warning:
Relation= child
; no model, key or relatedModel (function MainModel() {
              MainModel.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
            }, "nestedmodel", undefined)


Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

Simply removing the 'NestedModel' variable from the 1st line of generated JavaScript

```
var MainModel, NestedModel, mm, nm;
```

Causes the correct behaviour. Obviously I can't keep removing the variable definition from the generated JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

Ok, it appears to be a scoping issue. See the following [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/simax/nvm6H/3/). But why can't I just refer to the classes in the local function scope?

Answer (score 0):

> But why can't I just refer to the classes in the local function scope?

Classes are implemented as Immediately Invoked Function Expressions

> The key to understanding design patterns such as immediately-invoked function expressions is to realize JavaScript has function scope (but not block scope) and passes values by reference inside a closure.

**References**

- [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)